# FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql-13

I am getting the below errors every 2 or 3 days(when high usage of database) and also **postmaster.pid** file is changed automatically.
my Database version is postgresql 13

`Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode`

Out of memory: Kill process 2591 (postgres)

LOG: terminating any other active server processes

FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

below are the my configuration parameters
and my server capacity is 4cpu's and 16 GB RAM, please help me.

ALTER SYSTEM SET
max_connections = '400';

alter system set effective_io_concurrency=100

alter system set log_min_duration_statement=3000;

alter system set log_destination='stderr,csvlog'

alter system set  effective_cache_size = '8GB';

alter system set max_connections = '400';

alter system set work_mem = '6MB';  -
alter system set max_wal_size ='2GB';

alter system set max_worker_processes ='4';

alter system set max_parallel_workers ='4';

alter system set max_parallel_workers_per_gather ='4';   -

alter system set wal_keep_size ='500MB';

Comment: Why are you changing the `postmaster.pid` file? What did you do to put Postgres into the recovery mode, and why?

Comment: Sir I am not changing postmaster.pid file, It will changes automatically every 1 or 2 days, when that time below error is came the database system is in recovery mode